# WebSockets client for iOS 9 SDK Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sockets, websocket, socketrocket

Could any one suggest the best way to implement web sockets in iOS. I need to build using base sdks iOS 9 or above. 
Found her web socket client for iOS. (https://github.com/square/SocketRocket). Also read a thread on this here http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps. Can I use it for a project with base sdks iOS 9 and above? Is it the best solution for implementing the web socket in iOS? 
Also in the required libraries, libicucore.dylib is seen and will it be possible to include the library in Xcode 7 and above?

Answer (score 2):

I've used JetFire
https://github.com/acmacalister/jetfire to create this simple multiplayer game which I tested against [Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/14/azure-web-site-now-supports-websockets.aspx), [RedHat](https://www.openshift.com/), and [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets) using NodeJS for the backend.

Comment: Is the implementation of selfSignedCertificate is correct in JetFire?

Comment: @iGo In my case, I used the provider's certificate.  I didn't try to use my own certificate.  I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I would put this here, I created an iOS/Objective-C package for handling TLS with the new iOS 13 restrictions. Give it a shot if you are having trouble, it should be pretty easy to use. Contribute if possible!

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets